# Calling a local python script from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have the following requirement:

1.Need to call a python script which resides locally, from javascript. It will carry out some operations and return a xml file.

2.Then I need to return the xml file to the javascript.

3.The javascript will carry out the parsing of the xml and display the values in the HTML.

Can you kindly give me some pointers on how to carry out steps 1 and 2?I have tried to find answers to this but I haven't got a well defined solution.

Thanks,
Sayan

Comment: afaik the only way to get data from externally  is to make an ajax call so you would need to serve the python through a webserver or something ... I dont think you can execute files via javascript (this would be a huge security vunerability)

Comment: Are you also loading the page locally? You could just run a local webserver.

Comment: So I can call a python script from javascript via an ajax call ?

Comment: Ultimately the pages will reside in the server, after the development is done.So running a local webserver will not solve the problem

Comment: I am making a http call to a geoserver that resides in an outside domain.Whenever I make this call via javascript its giving me the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: I do not have access to the server code. So I cannot make any changes in the server code to stop this. So I made a call via python and got the xml.  So, if I am able to call this python script from javascript, it will solve my problem.Kindly help me out on how to call this python script from javascript and return the xml file to javascript.

Comment: Yep, that's the same-origin policy. You cannot make an Ajax call to an external domain, if that server if it doesn't allow it.

Comment: You still need to run a webserver somehow, somewhere. Then you just make an Ajax request to it, your python script executes and returns the XML. Basically your are adding a server that you control in between so that you can make it work with Ajax.

Comment: Exactly, so I decided to make the call via python and return that value to the javascript.I am getting the xml file via python.Now I only need to return the value to the javascript.Kindly  Help me on this !!

Comment: Yes, the webserver runs in an external domain, i.e. weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/

Comment: Can you kindly explain this with a small code snippet.Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: My previous comment explains his to solve the problem, what more do you need? You don't even have to setup a new one if there is an existing one that allows you to execute python and making Ajax calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your browser **can't** (and know you how to) **execute Python functions**/modules.
What you want is to make an [AJAX request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp). Basically, you need to put a web server in front of your Python function and then return the result of the function, here your XML file, when a certain URL is called.
There's a lot of lightweight web framework that should help you to setup a quick web server to do that. For instance, [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Here's an example, totally inspired from the homepage of Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from yourmodule import function_that_return_xml
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    xml = function_that_return_xml()
    # make fancy operations if you want
    return xml

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then, here you can call `http://localhost:5000` (default address, put it online if you want other users to use it) to get your XML file.

Comment: So, basically I make this proxy web server using flask, that calls the main geoserver and gets the xml.Then make AJAX calls to this proxy webserver and get the xml file in javascript, for displaying in HTML???