# Call certain Python function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I've searched this subject already for a bit on the Internet and I couldn't find anything decent:
I was wondering if it possible to call a single Python function from a Python file from JavaScript?

I already came across suggestions such as $ajax-requests, ([Call Python function from Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175510/call-python-function-from-javascript-code)) but this only seems to execute the `__main__` method of said Python file. Other suggestions I came across also just execute the entire Python file, without the possibility of just executing a single method of it.

What I want is for example a Python-class containing methods this:

```
def testMethod(self):
    print "testMethod called from JavaScript"
    return "It worked!"
```

and that I would be able to call this `testMethod()` from JavaScript (optionally with parameters etc. of course if the method expects them).

Is this possible in a simple way? I mention the word **simple** because frameworks like Flask etc. would be my last resort, I'd much more prefer something fast and doesn't change my webproject too much for the rest.

Comment: Are you using any particular python web framework ? Using Flask it would be quite simple.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942320/calling-a-local-python-script-from-javascript

Comment: I think you should use Flask and [this](http://codehandbook.org/python-flask-and-jquery-ajax-post/). should help

Comment: Why?  While there are certainly use cases, it would be much easier/better to do it in JavaScript.  If you absolutely must do this, I'd recommend looking into spawning a child process. Pass it command line arguments that trigger the specific function you want, with the specified arguments you want

Comment: No. AngularJS is being used as JavaScript framework though. But I have to call certain specific methods from my Python classes that can't be written in JavaScript